# How to make Custom UITableViewCell appear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with 2 grouped sections. In the first section, 3 out of the 4 static cells are `Right Detail` type, however the last one is a custom one with a `UILabel` and a `UISwitch`. However, in the simulator only the first 3 are appearing properly. The elements of the last one are appearing separately, below the others, however not on a `UITableViewCell`. How to fix this  ? Thanks

Here's what it looks like...
[image]

Comment: One screenshot is worth a thousand words...

Comment: Done. Added the screenshot

Comment: Aren't that views on the section's footer? Are you sure it's a cell you added there?

Comment: Looks like you're heightForRowAtIndexPath is off.

Comment: @galrito No, its a custom cell. Even the cell count for the sections is 4.

Comment: Show the code how you generate this table.

Comment: No code. Static cells.

Comment: Are you adding the constraints yourself or are you relying on what interface builder is generating for you? I'm saying this because I recreate the interface you have there and, if I don't create the constraints myself, the switch didn't even appear.